# Google CSE, Google Scholar search

Tags: wordpress, google-custom-search

So I am trying to embed a google scholar search into a WordPress site. I have the embedding part working, but how can I make the search show results only from google scholar. I have read through the tutorials google has posted, but I am not entirely sure which section I should be using.

There is an option to make the search an image search is there a way to do this for Google Scholar?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be pretty old but my answer might help someone looking for the same.

Google scholar does not provide any official API for querying and fetching the results.

But you can achieve the same by scrapping i.e querying and then parsing the data returned by Google scholar.

There is a [python parser](https://github.com/ckreibich/scholar.py) already available which you can customize and integrate within your application using a custom plugin.

Hope it helps.